# Show that $ \max\big\{ (1-x)(1-y) , xy , x(1-y) + y(1-x)\big \} \geq \dfrac49$ for $x,y \in [0,1]$.

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, analysis, optimization

For $x$ and $y$ in the interval $[0,1]$, show that
$$\max\big\{ (1-x)(1-y) , xy  , x(1-y) + y(1-x) \big\}\geq \frac49$$
 I have been thinking on this for some time but couldn't get to prove it, any inputs are welcome.

Comment: can you use the fact $(1-x)(1-y) + xy + x(1-y) + y(1-x)= 1$ and try to prove terms are sufficiently different

Comment: Since all expressions are symmetric, we may without loss of generality assume that $x \geq y$. Note then that if $y \geq 2/3$ then we would have $xy \geq y^2 \geq \frac{4}{9}$. We may thus assume that $y \leq 2/3$. By the same logic we must have that $1-x \geq 2/3$ since $1-x \leq 1- y$ and otherwise we would have $(1-x)(1-y) \geq 4/9$. We have then $1/3 \leq x \leq y \leq 2/3$.  So we have a smaller interval we need to verify this in. Does that help?

Comment: Yeah i did this and got an idea, to proceed further.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $s:=x+y$ and $m:=xy$.  We have
$$0\leq s\leq 2\text{ and }0\leq m\leq \frac{s^2}{4}\,.$$  The three functions to be compared are
$$a:=(1-x)(1-y)=1-s+m\,,\,\,b:=xy=m\,,\text{ and }c:=x(1-y)+y(1-x)=s-2m\,.$$
If $0\leq s\leq \dfrac{2}{3}$, then $m\leq \dfrac{s^2}{4}\leq  \dfrac{1}{9}$, implying
$$a+c=1-m\geq \frac{8}{9}\,,\text{ whence }a\geq \frac{4}{9}\text{ or }c\geq \frac{4}{9}\,.$$
If $\dfrac{2}{3}\leq s\leq \dfrac{4}{3}$, then $|s-1|\leq \dfrac13$, whence
$$(s-1)^2\leq \frac{1}{9}\,,\text{ or }s-\frac{s^2}{2}\geq \frac{4}{9}\,.$$
Ergo,
$$c=s-2m\geq s-\frac{s^2}{2} \geq \frac{4}{9}\,.$$
Finally, suppose that $\dfrac{4}{3}\leq s\leq 2$.  Then,
$$2b+c=s\geq \frac{4}{3}\,,\text{ making }b\geq \frac{4}{9}\text{ or }c\geq \frac{4}{9}\,.$$
Hence, we do have
$$\frac49\leq \max\big\{(1-x)(1-y),xy,x(1-y)+y(1-x)\big\}\leq 1\text{ for all }x,y\in[0,1]\,,$$
whose left-hand side is an equality is an equality iff $(x,y)=\left(\dfrac13,\dfrac13\right)$ or $(x,y)=\left(\dfrac23,\dfrac23\right)$, and whose right-hand side is an equality iff $x\in\{0,1\}$ and $y\in\{0,1\}$.

---

Interestingly, we also have
$$0\leq \min\big\{(1-x)(1-y),xy,x(1-y)+y(1-x)\big\}\leq \frac14\text{ for all }x,y\in[0,1]\,,$$
where the left-hand side is an equality iff $x\in\{0,1\}$ or $y\in\{0,1\}$, and the right-hand side is an equality iff $(x,y)=\left(\dfrac12,\dfrac12\right)$.  Here is a proof of the right-hand side inequality above.  If $0\leq s\leq 1$, then we get
$$b=m\leq \frac{s^2}{4}\leq \dfrac14\,.$$
If $1\leq s\leq 2$, then we have
$$a=1-s+m\leq 1-s+\frac{s^2}{4}=\frac{(2-s)^2}{4}\leq \frac{1}{4}\,.$$

Furthermore, the median satisfies
$$0\leq\text{med}\big((1-x)(1-y),xy,x(1-y)+y(1-x)\big)\leq \frac12\,.$$
The left-hand side inequality becomes an equality iff $x\in\{0,1\}$ and $y\in\{0,1\}$.  The right-hand side inequality becomes an equality iff $\{x,y\}=\left\{0,\dfrac12\right\}$ or $\{x,y\}=\left\{\dfrac12,1\right\}$.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this helped, this was what i was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Idea:

Instead of $y$ write $a$. Now we have $3$ linear functions $$f(x) = x(1-2a)+a$$ $$g(x) =x(a-1)+1-a$$ $$h(x) = ax$$

Now if $a\geq {2\over 3}$ then $f$ is entirely above $g$ but $f$ and $h$ intersect at $x_0={a\over 3a-1}$

In this case $$f(x_0) = {a^2\over 3a-1}\geq {4\over 9}$$

The same porcedure we do for $a\leq 1/3$ and $1/3\leq a\leq 2/3$...

Comment: I did and plotted a graph for the limits, it helped "seeing" and it helped continue further.